# R glmnet and elasticnet gives different results, why?

Tags: r, machine-learning, elastic-net

My question is simple: when glmnet use alpha between 0 and 1 (i.e. elastic net), is it returning naive elastic net or adjusted one? Especially, for every method inbuilt (coef, cv.glmnet, predict) is it naive or adjusted?

The reason I am wondering about this is because I cannot align glmnet with enet.

```
require(ISLR)
library(glmnet)
library(elasticnet)
x=model.matrix(Apps~.,College)[,-1]
y=College$Apps
enet.model=enet(x,y,lambda=1)
predict(enet.model,type="coef",s=2,mode="penalty")
glmnet.model=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0.5)
coef(glmnet.model,s=4,exact=TRUE)
```

They give different results, why?

Comment: Is there any reason not to share the results with us? It might make it easier for people to see what is going on.

Comment: Sorry I will be doing right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x=model.matrix(Apps~.,College)[,-1]
y=College$Apps

enet.model=enet(x, y, lambda=1)
mx_x <- data.frame(coef_enet = round(predict(enet.model, type="coef", s=2, mode="penalty", naive = F)$coefficients, 2))
mx_x$coef_enet.naive <- round(predict(enet.model, type="coef", s=2, mode="penalty", naive = T)$coefficients, 2)

glmnet.model=glmnet(x, y, alpha=0.50)
mx_x$coef_glmnet <- round(coef(glmnet.model, s=2, exact=TRUE), 2)[-1]

mx_x
```

The script above gives:

```
               coef_enet coef_enet.naive coef_glmnet

PrivateYes   -1125.13         -562.56     -493.72
Accept           0.85            0.43        1.57
Enroll           1.44            0.72       -0.80
Top10perc       26.13           13.06       48.90
Top25perc       17.20            8.60      -13.47
F.Undergrad      0.25            0.12        0.05
P.Undergrad      0.21            0.10        0.04
Outstate         0.02            0.01       -0.08
Room.Board       0.31            0.15        0.15
Books            0.70            0.35        0.02
Personal         0.12            0.06        0.03
PhD             11.77            5.88       -8.53
Terminal        10.30            5.15       -3.31
S.F.Ratio       23.87           11.93       14.97
perc.alumni    -17.08           -8.54       -0.01
Expend           0.09            0.05        0.08
Grad.Rate       19.05            9.52        8.51
```

Using *naive=FALSE* for ElasticNet is just transforming the coefficients of *naive=TRUE* according to formula:
coef(ENet) = (1 + lambda) * coef(NaiveENet)

The glmnet gives "ready-to-use" coefficients. However they are different from those of ElasticNet. (maybe different algorithms)

You'll get ElasticNet and glmnet "aligned" if you don't normalize the predictors.

```
enet.model=enet(x, y, lambda=1, normalize = F)
mx_x <- data.frame(coef_enet = round(predict(enet.model, type="coef", s=2,     mode="penalty", naive = F)$coefficients, 2))
mx_x$coef_enet.naive <- round(predict(enet.model, type="coef", s=2, mode="penalty", naive = T)$coefficients, 2)

glmnet.model=glmnet(x, y, alpha=0.50, standardize = F)
mx_x$coef_glmnet <- round(coef(glmnet.model, s=2, exact=TRUE), 2)[-1]

mx_x



        coef_enet coef_enet.naive coef_glmnet
PrivateYes    -971.26         -485.63     -481.73
Accept           3.17            1.59        1.58
Enroll          -1.76           -0.88       -0.87
Top10perc       99.84           49.92       49.57
Top25perc      -28.47          -14.24      -14.03
F.Undergrad      0.12            0.06        0.06
P.Undergrad      0.09            0.04        0.04
Outstate        -0.17           -0.09       -0.09
Room.Board       0.30            0.15        0.15
Books            0.04            0.02        0.02
Personal         0.06            0.03        0.03
PhD            -17.29           -8.65       -8.54
Terminal        -6.59           -3.30       -3.35
S.F.Ratio       31.04           15.52       15.48
perc.alumni      0.31            0.16        0.09
Expend           0.16            0.08        0.08
Grad.Rate       17.31            8.66        8.63
```

How predict works?

```
mx_x2 <- data.frame(pred_enet = predict(enet.model, newx=x, s=2, mode="penalty", naive=F)$fit,
pred_enet.naive = predict(enet.model, newx=x, s=2, mode="penalty", naive=T)$fit,
pred_glmnet = as.vector(predict(glmnet.model, newx=x, s=2, exact=T)))
head(mx_x2)

                          pred_enet pred_enet.naive pred_glmnet
Abilene Christian University  -200.7408       1400.4488   1403.1934
Adelphi University            3757.6684       3379.6534   3376.7797
Adrian College                -456.4379       1272.6002   1272.1445
Agnes Scott College            994.5582       1998.0983   1997.6611
Alaska Pacific University    -3453.9529       -226.1573   -221.7383
Albertson College            -1664.2285        668.7049    668.3047
```

enet prediction is linear in enet naive prediction (formula):

```
fit.lm <- lm(pred_enet~pred_enet.naive, data=mx_x2)
coef(fit.lm)
(Intercept) pred_enet.naive 
  -3001.638           2.000 
summary(fit.lm)$r.squared
[1] 1
```

enet naive is almost identical to glmnet prediction:

```
fit.lm <- lm(pred_enet.naive~-1+pred_glmnet, data=mx_x2)
coef(fit.lm)
pred_glmnet 
1.000126
summary(fit.lm)$r.squared
[1] 0.9999994
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still having following questions:

Comment: Why you use s=2 for glmnet? Isn't lambda=4 letting them having the same penalties? Also did predict and cv method in glmnet use naive coefficients?

Comment: @YuanTao  _"Why you use s=2 for glmnet? Isn't lambda=4 letting them having the same penalties?"_ I can't figure this out from authors' materials:  elasticnet: http://users.stat.umn.edu/~zouxx019/Papers/elasticnet.pdf      glmnet: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html    so I just assumed is the same or close to the same penalty when using s=2. To have exactly the same penalties, I think, alpha should be also changed.   I have edited the answer for the second part of your question.